# "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" using two different date comparisons in a Snowflake UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I get the above error (in what is a perfectly legal query) when using a UDF as so:

```
SELECT
  dd.date,
  person_count(dd.date) AS cnt
FROM dim_date dd
WHERE dd.date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-07'
```

Essentially, this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_count(d date)
  RETURNS number 
  AS 
  $$
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
   FROM persons
   WHERE (deceased_date > d)
  $$;
```

And this produces the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_count(d date)
  RETURNS number 
  AS 
  $$
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
   FROM persons
   WHERE (deceased_date = '1901-01-01' OR deceased_date > d)
  $$;
```

I've tried using `TO_DATE` on the date string. I've tried using `deceased_date < '1901-01-02'` and I've tried converting all dates to strings. Nothing seems to work. I'm thinking this may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Going to take it up with Snowflake support.

Comment: For those following, I contacted support and they say that ORs are not supported in subquery due to some optimizations they do. They claim they are working on support for "some subquery types" that should come out in the next year.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed the first code works,

```
create or replace table persons (person_id number, deceased_date date);
insert into persons values (1,'2019-10-01'),(1,'2019-09-01'),(2,'1901-01-01'),(3,'2019-11-04');

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
    FROM persons
    WHERE (deceased_date = '1901-01-01' OR deceased_date > '2019-11-04');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_count(d date)
    RETURNS number 
    AS 
    $$
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
     FROM persons
     WHERE (deceased_date > d)
    $$;

 select column1 as date
    ,person_count(column1) as cnt 
 from values ('2019-11-01'), ('2019-11-02'), ('2019-11-03'), ('2019-11-04'), ('2019-11-05'), ('2019-11-06'), ('2019-11-07')
 order by 1;
```

But these alternative do not.
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_count(d date)
      RETURNS number 
      AS 
      $$
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
       FROM persons
       WHERE (deceased_date = '1901-01-01' OR deceased_date > d)
      $$;

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_count(d date)
  RETURNS number 
  AS 
  $$
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id)
  FROM (
    SELECT person_id FROM PERSONS WHERE deceased_date > d
    UNION 
    SELECT person_id FROM PERSONS WHERE deceased_date = '1901-01-01'
  )
  $$;
```

The reason is, when they expand the FUNCTION they turn it into a correlated sub-query (even though it could be done as a JOIN) and the only work with very simple correlated sub-queries, and you have not control of this. We have banged our head against this when want to use TABLE FUNCTIONS as look-up tables. In one place we just rolled out a CASE statement to avoid the lookup (gross) and in another we used Javascript UDFs to do the lookup.

But it's fundamentally is a bug, so I would report it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there is some limitation with OR predicate in subquery support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the UDF has nothing to do with the error.  It seems Snowflake does syntactical substitution during query parsing where ever possible, and in this case ends up with:

```
SELECT
  dd.date,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) 
   FROM persons
   WHERE (deceased_date = '1901-01-01' OR deceased_date > dd.date)) AS cnt
FROM dim_date dd
WHERE dd.date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-07';
```

Which produces the exact same error.  As [Seeling Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9175875/seeling-cheung) mentions, this only fails when there are multiple WHERE conditions.

Query parsing with subqueries (correlated or not) combined with multiple condition filtering seems to be a continuous problem for Snowflake, eg. [Bug in Date Cast](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009bSBMySAO/bug-in-date-cast)...